# In memory weighted graph for a linked data (RDF)

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, rdf

It is a subset of dbpedia dataset which needs to be loaded in memory.

- Operation will mainly involve traversing the graph based on edge weights in both directions
- 3 types of queries

  1. Finding Path between 2 nodes
  2. Given Subject and Predicate find object.
  3. Given Object and Predicate find subject.
- It is a sparse Graph
- Performance w.r.t time is important
- Implementation Language: Java
- Use of weights: *Filtering*. The edges with weight higher than some threshold will be selected.
  As it will be a sparse graph, using the Matrix data structure will be *HIGHLY* space inefficient.

Initial idea was to make java-objects for every `subject` and let each subject store a 2d array of 3 columns for `predicate`, `object` and `weight`.
But with this kind of data structure it will be hard to generate a list of subjects given an object. Even though it is good with generating the objects given subject.

Is there any proper(more time efficient) way to achieve this? Which could make traversals in both directions easier.

The graph in question is [Categories(SKOS)](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2015-04#categories-skos)

Comment: Could you describe the graph traversal / queries (based on edge weights) that you intend to perform on this data?

Comment: Mainly 3 types if queries: 1. FInding Path between 2 nodes. 2. Given Subject and Predicate find object. 3. 2. Given Object and Predicate find subject

Comment: those are simple queries that can done using SPARQL. how are edge weights used in these queries?

Comment: I need the whole thing in java as java data types...so that I can traverse it in java.

Comment: OK, but what is the role of those weights? Do they play role in queries? Or are they just included query results (and not used for e.g. filtering in queries)?

Comment: Filtering. I'll take the edges with weight higher than some threshold

Comment: Please add this information to your question. The way you want to query the data is an important part of the question.

Comment: Does your task require you to implement these data structures yourself? In case if it does not then a better approach is to use a graph-oriented data store that already has all the optimizations built in.

Comment: Yes. Iam supposed to implement this myself

Comment: Then "to implement it myself" probably means you can not use existing graph stores (though I wonder why make such a condition). If so, explore how these stores (e.g. RDF stores) index information and implement a similar approach. For query types 2, 3 you can index triples by (subj+predicate) and by (object+predicate) respectively.